# What's slowing down this piece of python code?

Tags: python-2.7, nlp

I have been trying to implement the Stupid Backoff language model (the description is available [here](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D07-1090.pdf), though I believe the details are not relevant to the question).

The thing is, the code's working and producing the result that is expected, but works slower than I expected. I figured out the part that was slowing down everything is here (and NOT in the training part):

```
def compute_score(self, sentence):
    length = len(sentence)
    assert length <= self.n
    if length == 1:
        word = tuple(sentence)
        return float(self.ngrams[length][word]) / self.total_words
    else:
        words = tuple(sentence[::-1])
        count = self.ngrams[length][words]
        if count == 0:
            return self.alpha * self.compute_score(sentence[1:])
        else:
            return float(count) / self.ngrams[length - 1][words[:-1]]

def score(self, sentence):
""" Takes a list of strings as argument and returns the log-probability of the 
    sentence using your language model. Use whatever data you computed in train() here.
"""
    output = 0.0
    length = len(sentence)
    for idx in range(length):
        if idx < self.n - 1:
            current_score = self.compute_score(sentence[:idx+1])
        else:
            current_score = self.compute_score(sentence[idx-self.n+1:idx+1])
        output += math.log(current_score)
    return output
```

self.ngrams is a nested dictionary that has n entries. Each of these entries is a dictionary of form (word_i, word_i-1, word_i-2.... word_i-n) : the count of this combination.

self.alpha is a constant that defines the penalty for going n-1.

self.n is the maximum length of that tuple that the program is looking for in the dictionary self.ngrams. It is set to 3 (though setting it to 2 or even 1 doesn't anything). It's weird because the Unigram and Bigram models work just fine in fractions of a second.

The answer that I am looking for is not a refactored version of my own code, but rather a tip which part of it is the most computationally expensive (so that I could figure out myself how to rewrite it and get the most educational profit from solving this problem).

Please, be patient, I am but a beginner (two months into the world of programming). Thanks.

UPD:
I timed the running time with the same data using time.time():

Unigram = 1.9

[Bigram](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3abbdd1b20102e1bf233ccbfe3912d01) = 3.2

Stupid Backoff (n=2) = 15.3

Stupid Backoff (n=3) = 21.6

(It's on some bigger data than originally because of time.time's bad precision.)

Comment: If the code is working, and you're just looking for peer review to optimize it, you should be asking on [codereview.se] instead. This site is for questions about problems you're having with getting code to work in the first place.

Comment: @KenWhite: Whether a question is on topic for Stack Overflow does not depend on whether the code is producing incorrect results or whether the question would also be on topic for Code Review. This question is at least as on topic as any "why is my output including extra spaces" or "why is my list empty" question. We have a concrete problem - runtime substantially longer than expected - and the question is looking for a specific answer about what's causing that problem, not general code improvement. The question doesn't need to be moved.

Comment: @user2357112: CR was created specifically for this purpose. I didn't vote to close; I made a suggestion. CR was created to review working code for optimization purposes. Code that produces incorrect results is not working code, and neither is code that *produces extra spaces* or *an empty list*, so your reference to them is irrelevant. If no question is suitable for migrating to CR, why does it exist in the first place? If you want do discuss it's existence or relevance, take that to [meta]. (There is also no *substantially longer* mentioned, just *slower than expected*.)

Comment: That said, I don't see anything here that would cause a catastrophic performance problem. Do the unigram and bigram models just look like this with `self.n` set to 1 or 2? How much slower is this than the other models, and how fast were you expecting it to be? If the other models finish in fractions of a second, I would only expect this to take a second or two. We may need to see a runnable [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @KenWhite: Code Review was created for code review. If you look at the [Area 51 proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464?phase=definition), it says the site is for "getting extensive feedback/review of best practices, design pattern usage, application UI, security, etc." Optimization isn't the sole or even primary focus; it's secondary enough to be folded into the "etc".

Comment: @user2357112: And that invalidates a suggestion to use it? This question (while well written) isn't even specific; it asks for *rather a tip which part of it is the most computationally expensive* instead of asking for a problem solution. That's asking for code review, IMO; tips regarding what most impacts performance.

Comment: @user2357112: Bigram and Unigram are different in a sense that they do not back off if a specific combination is not in the dictionary. Instead, they just mark it as "unseen" and assign a very low (yet non-zero) probability to them. Stupid Backoff with n=3, for instancem, first tries Trigram, if it's unseen, it backs off to Bigram, then to Unigram. I updated the post with the timings.

Comment: That's... not fractions of a second for the unigram and bigram models.

Comment: With this timing info and the provided bigram scoring code, it just looks like you had bad expectations. Your Stupid Backoff code is doing about 5-7 times as much work per iteration, and it's taking 5-7 times as long.

Comment: For example, your bigram code just builds a bigram and looks up that bigram's score directly in the model dict. Your Stupid Backoff code goes through an entire computation to score an n-gram. If you precomputed n-gram scores for your Stupid Backoff code like you did for your bigram code, sentence scoring would go faster.

Comment: @user2357112 I had to use a larger dataset to capture the timing, otherwise I would get zero for Unigram and Bigram. Thanks for the time you spent answering my question. Should I somehow mark it as solved or just delete it?

Answer (score 0):

If the sentence is very long, most of the code that's actually running is here:

```
def score(self, sentence):
    for idx in range(len(sentence)): # should use xrange in Python 2!
        self.compute_score(sentence[idx-self.n+1:idx+1])

def compute_score(self, sentence):
    words = tuple(sentence[::-1])
    count = self.ngrams[len(sentence)][words]
    if count == 0:
        self.compute_score(sentence[1:])
    else:
        self.ngrams[len(sentence) - 1][words[:-1]]
```

That's not meant to be working code--it just removes the unimportant parts.

The flow in the critical path is therefore:

- For each word in the sentence:

  - Call `compute_score()` on that word plus the following 2.  This creates a new list of length 3.  You could avoid that with `itertools.islice()`.

    - Construct a 3-tuple with the words reversed.  This creates a new tuple.  You could avoid that by passing the `-1` step argument when making the slice outside this function.
    - Look up in `self.ngrams`, a nested dict, with the first key being a number (might be faster if this level were a list; there are only three keys anyway?), and the second being the tuple just created.
    - Recurse with the first word removed, i.e. make a new tuple `(sentence[2], sentence[1])`, or
    - Do another lookup in `self.ngrams`, implicitly creating another new tuple `(words[:-1])`.

In summary, I think the biggest problem you have  is the repeated and nested creation and destruction of lists and tuples.